# button_object.findViewByid(R.id.button_id) & button_object=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id)

Tags: android, findviewbyid

what is difference between finding button by button_object.findViewById(R.id.button_id) & button_object=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id) in android studio?

Comment: The difference is the second one works, the first one does not. The first one is just _not_ how to find and assign a `Button` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The second one casts the method to a Button type object, which I believe is not necessary in newer verions of Android Studio. So they do the same in those cases.

Comment: The first one gave me an error : "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference" and the second one solved the error. May I know why?

Comment: In never versions of Android Studio and Sdk, that shouldn't matter,as long as, of course you are writing both of them correctly (and declaring those buttons before the onCreate method):

button_object=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button_object=findViewById(R.id.button_id);

Answer (score 0):

-The syntax `(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id)` is return object of `Button` .

-for specific view `view.findViewById(R.id.button_id)` returns the `Button` inside the view that is not in this case. because you don't have button inside button. so it will give `NullPointerException`

for example if you use fragment in that case we are using the second point, in that we have button inside view.

I think you got my point.